# ImageView scale to parent width and save image proportion

Tags: android, xml, layout, imageview, scale

The problem is described in the image below:

Comment: as your requirement is not a std scaleType use scaleType="matrix" and compute the Matrix to match your needs

Comment: how do i compute the matrix?

Comment: you can use `preScale`/`postScale` methods, see `android.graphics.Matrix` docs for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can set its ScaleType. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).